# SSL Error with stackstorm sensor connection to redis

Tags: python, ssl, redis, eventlet

Getting these errors while connecting to redis with SSL. A normal action runs fine, sensor seems to be having problem. I did try to use the fixes mentioned in https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/371 but none of the different combinations of library versions seem to work for my case.

````
021-08-17 14:32:25,839 WARNING [-] Sensor "XYZSensor" run method raised an exception: Error while reading from socket: ('timed out',).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 198, in _read_from_socket
    data = recv(self._sock, socket_read_size)
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/_compat.py", line 72, in recv
    return sock.recv(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 231, in recv
    return self._base_recv(buflen, flags, into=False)
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 258, in _base_recv
    read = self.read(nbytes)
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 176, in read
    super(GreenSSLSocket, self).read, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 156, in _call_trampolining
    timeout_exc=timeout_exc('timed out'))
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/__init__.py", line 159, in trampoline
    return hub.switch()
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 298, in switch
    return self.greenlet.switch()
ssl.SSLError: ('timed out',)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/st2reactor/container/sensor_wrapper.py", line 229, in run
    self._sensor_instance.run()
  File "/opt/stackstorm/packs/st2sensors/sensors/vmc_event_notification_sensor.py", line 56, in run
    self.pubsub.subscribe('XYZEvents')
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 3580, in subscribe
    ret_val = self.execute_command('SUBSCRIBE', *iterkeys(new_channels))
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 3468, in execute_command
    self.shard_hint
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1203, in get_connection
    if connection.can_read():
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 734, in can_read
    return self._parser.can_read(timeout)
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 321, in can_read
    return self._buffer and self._buffer.can_read(timeout)
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 231, in can_read
    raise_on_timeout=False)
  File "/opt/stackstorm/st2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 223, in _read_from_socket
    (ex.args,))
    ```
````

Comment: Any chance you solved this? I'm running into a similar error when trying to reach an aws elasticache redis cluster from a nameko service.